# Не отправляются данные на сервер. Прошу помочь где капать

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Не могу отправить данные из php в базу данных mysql. Данные получаю через js, потом через Ajax передаю их в php, а уже от туда хочу отправить в mysql, однако ничего не получается. Вот что пишет сам браузер:
[image: Ошибка в браузере]

И сам код:
JS код (checkTests.js):

```
    // Отправка данных на сервер
$(document).on('click', '.checkBtn', function(){
    let userPoints = getCookie('points'),
        allPoints = getCookie('allPoints');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../js/updateDB.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            userPoints: userPoints,
            allPoints: allPoints,
        }, success: function(){
            console.log('Данные отправлены!')
        }
    })
})
```

php код (updateDB.php):

```
<?php
    $arr['userPoints'] = $_POST['userPoints'];
    $arr['allPoints'] = $_POST['allPoints'];

    echo json_encode($arr);

    $userPoints = $arr['userPoints'];
    $allPoints = $arr['allPoints'];


    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $password = md5($password.'afm430fx0a');

    include 'connect.php';

    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");

    $mysql = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $mysql->query("INSERT INTO users (points) VALUES ('$userPoints')");
    // $mysql->query("INSERT INTO `goals` (`allPoints`) VALUES ('$userPoints')");

    $mysql->close();

    header("Location: /");

?>
```

Comment: Могу кнш ошибаться.. А разве не нужно в php для начала объявить `$arr = [];`? Кхм.. По видимому нет. Смотрите на вкладке `network` что вернулось, если php ошибки не выключены, вы поймете в чем проблема.

Comment: 500 - ошибка на сервере. так что берём в руки отладку и смотрим что там не так... + вывод ошибок

Comment: скорее всего код php неверный, в консоли же видно что сервер возвращает.